# Can't convert input element to re-usable component in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a login form and now I want to convert my input fields to re- usable component. I created separate common input.jsx file. This is input.jsx file's code.

```jsx
import React from "react";

const Input = ({ name, label, value, onChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
      <input
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        id={name}
        name={name}
        type="text"
        className="form-control"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

and imported it to my loginForm.jsx. Here is my loginForm.jsx render method

```jsx
handleChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
  const account = { ...this.state.account };
  account[input.name] = input.value;
  this.setState({ account });
};

render() {
  const { account } = this.state;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Input
          name="username"
          value={account.username}
          label="Username"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <Input
          name="password"
          value={account.password}
          label="Password"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />

        <button className="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But after adding below code to my loginForm.jsx,

```jsx
<Input
  name="username"
  value={account.username}
  label="Username"
  onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

code and deleted previous code ,

```jsx
<div className="form-group">
  <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
  <input
    value={account.username}
    name="username"
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    ref={this.username}
    id="username"
    type="text"
    className="form-control"
  />
</div>
```

suddenly my login page not loading.(Empty page).

My login page's console showing below error.

```
The above error occurred in the <LoginForm> component:

at LoginForm (http://localhost:3000/main.5d4e82bfe117bc198b43.hot-update.js:27:5)
at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:54444:5)
at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:54739:5)
at main
at App
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:54612:5)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:53870:5)
```

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

Comment: where did you define the handleChange method. post code

Comment: In the loginForm.jsx, before the render method. I will add that code snippest to my question. Please find it.

Comment: seems like in one component you are using the class component and another one using the functional component approach. try using one approach. use render method inside Input component

Comment: You seem to have cut off the first part of the error message. Please [edit] your question to include all the relevant details

Comment: [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: This is not reproducible ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-meadow-3ulvqb?file=/src/LoginForm.jsx